# "Al" as a reduction of “Alexander”

Tags: abbreviations, names, proper-nouns

Can I use *Al* as a reduction of the name *Alexander*?

Is this reduction clear to native English speakers?

Comment: You can use whatever Alexander is happy with! (Most British Alexanders seem to be Alex)

Comment: "Al" feels more like *chemistry*....

Comment: How about "A"? "Al" is a bit formal in some contexts.

Comment: Most "Als" I have known have been Alberts, but if your Alexander is OK with it, I see no problem.

Comment: I don't think simply stating "Al" is close enough to get to Alexander without an explanation. If I heard "Al', my first thoughts would be Alfred, Albert and Alan. Add to that Alasdair, Alain, etc.

Comment: Knowing the context would help here. I know Alexanders that have gone by Sandy, Al, Alex, and Sasha. If this is for a person you know, it is best to *ask them first*.

Comment: @Andrew: Under what circumstances could you possibly use this information? If you need to address Alexander, Alexandra, Alistair, Alan, Alison, or whoever, *that's* their name - unless they say *"My name's Alxxxxx, but [you can call me Al](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULjCSK0oOlI)" when you first meet.

Comment: I agree with @JohnP, but, as a side note, [Alexander Haig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Haig) was known by [Al](http://books.google.com/books?id=JFOFuaEMcgoC&pg=PA140&dq=%22al+haig%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Acv5UOXxBKH20gGr74GoBw&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22al%20haig%22&f=false), so it's not like this is without precedent.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: In the U.S. at least, "Al" is not formal at all; it's usually a shortened form of Alan, or some other Al- name.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of Carlo_R's comment is if he thinks this is talking about an abbreviation in writing, for example in a list of names. But in modern English it is almost unknown to use more than one letter in that context.

Comment: What if Algernon is also there, and known as 'Al'?

Answer (score 6):

*Al* is used as a contraction of *Alexander*, and also of *Alan* and other names.

*Alexander* is sometimes contracted to *Alex*, *Lex* or *Xander*.

As a rule, I wouldn't contract any name until I've heard the contraction used by someone else for the person in question — preferably that person themselves. What one person of that name might be happy with, another might detest.

Comment: Not to mention *Sandy* and *Sasha*. *Sasha* is Russian and I believe *Sandy* is Scottish, although I know people in the U.S. who use these nicknames.

Comment: @PeterShor - If you're gonna go Russian, then you also have "Sanya", "Shura", and "Shurik"; "Sasha" and "Shura" are also used for "Aleksandra".  Interestingly, "Alex" is usually short for "Alexei", which is a different name altogether.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on "where" and "how" you use it.

If you are dealing with someone you know for example, Al might be appropriate, though a bit unusual (normally one would use Alex). I would suggest if this is the case that you ask the person which they prefer.

However, if, let's say, you are writing a book, you would want to avoid using "Al" for Alexander as it's not a very common contraction of the name (so it would "feel strange" to a reader. On the flip side, you're free as a writer to choose to call someone whatever you like ;).